# iOS app with ASI shows lots of 'redefinition' afrer switch compiler to Apple LLVM

Tags: ios, compiler-construction, asihttprequest

I was intended to import a third party map kit to my project.Before that I already used ASI as network module, and the **compiler for C/C++/Objective-C** was **LLVM GCC 4.2**.But it didn't work with my third party map kit.So I switched to **Apple LLVM compiler 4.2**,which is a default compiler,but lots of errors showed the redefinition of ASI classes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make Clean
2. Delete derived data

Advice switch to [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which is far more better that good old ASIHTTP. I used to love it and saved my arse hundreds of times.

[There's an adapter for ASIHTTP code as well](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking-ASIHTTPRequest)